# Get image src from ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image, response

I'm trying to change an image source with an image path I'm getting from a php handler with ajax.

What I'm catching is: "img/blah.jpg"

This is my ajax:

```
$('.name').click( function() {
    //var e = $(this).attr('src','img/no.png'); //this works

$.ajax({ 
        url:'handler.php?blahid='.$idnum,
        type:"GET", 
        success: function(data)
        {
            var f = $(this).attr("src", data); //$(this) is the image I click on that I want to replace
            console.log(f);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrow)
        {
            debugger;
        }
    })
}
```

The ajax does its job when I click on the image I want to change. Perhaps I'm using the response data in an incorrect way. I used console log to see what I got and it returned an object. So I guess my problem is: what I'm doing now is not working and I'm not sure why. Let me know if you want me to clarify anything. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post what you return in function through handler.php?

Comment: @Yadav Chetan What returns is a few things depending on different conditions, but what I expect is either this: img/image1.png or img/image2.png. EDIT: The object that returns in the ajax response contains either img/image2.png or img/image1.png

Comment: Try console.log($(this).attr)

Comment: @tickerll follow the Rohan answer that will do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$('.publish').click( function() {
    var self=this; // add this line   
    $.ajax({ 
            url:'handler.php?blahid='.$idnum,
            type:"GET", 
            success: function(data)
            {
                var f = $(self).attr("src", data); // use self instead of this
                console.log(f);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrow)
            {
                debugger;
            }
     });
}
```

Comment: Is the #imageId coming from the handler or is it the id of the image that I want to replace?

Comment: It is the id of image whose src you want to change.

Comment: I forgot to mention that there are numerous images, which is why I used $(this) in order to change that specific one instead of all of the images. Sorry I didn't quite mention that... EDIT: When I try it statically outside of ajax on click of that image, it works, such as: $(this).attr("src", 'img/image2.png'); but when I use ajax with response, it doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: @tickerll test the above answer I have made changes.

Comment: However, when I try to click on the image again after it has changed, the image does not change. It remains the same. This is probably due to the fact that the image tag  contains an id (either 0 or 1) that I passed to the handler, and depending on whether it's 0 or 1, I would update the new data to the opposite number. This would mean I would need to return the full img tag from the handler with the number 1 or 0. In this case, i've tried using the find function. Would using this method work in the answer you provided as well? I will give it a try.. Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
var my_data = data;
var f = my_data.find('img').attr("src");
```

or you can directly use

```
$(data).find('img').attr('src');
```

Comment: Ajax data returns only `src` not the `img object`. Please see OP question.

Comment: @Gautam3164 When I return the full img tag from the handler and use this method that you provided, it returns undefined or an uncaught typeError: Object has no method 'find'

Answer (score 0):

in your example `$(this).attr("src", data);` $(this) points to ajax request. to change the image you can provide image id as below `$('#imageId').attr("src", data);`

Answer (score 0):

For data-location-image, be sure at database, like http:http://localhost/new_accemo_upd_1/data/scan-yr-201...

From Adding data:

```
data.append('gambar', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
```

Saving data (server)

```
'gambar' : base_url($_FILES['gambar'])
```

If we want to Edit image:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "<?php echo site_url(name-url)?>/",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data)
    {
       $('[name="logo"]').attr("src", data.logo);

    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        alert('Error get data from ajax');
    }
});
```

View HTML :

```
<img src="" name="logo"/>
```