# Display image using ajax garbled text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

hope you can help me, i have PHP script that generate image(get image using curl) it is call via ajax,when i directly access the php script(not using ajax) image is successfully generated but when call via ajax it display garbled text. Do you know the reason of this?

PHP SCRIPT:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
header('Content-Length: ' . get_size($songname));
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Javascript:

```
$.post(baseUrl+"getphoto.php",{photo:path }).done(function( data ) {
    console.log('#thumb_'+id);
    //garbled text appear on firebug
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

you create image dynamically
thus you need add header of Content-Type

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
```

to getphoto.php

Comment: i already have content type see my above code,image is generated when i access the getphoto.php on browser but via ajax garbled text show

Comment: ya.you must set recived data in src of an img element. you can not directly show image source

Comment: you mean that the garbled text is normal? it will not show the actual image on ajax response?

Comment: you must use your ajax response for change src of one img element see:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16601667/